# What is the meaning of: “a sword will pierce your soul”?

Tags: catholicism, exegesis, virgin-mary, rosary

One of the joyful mysteries talks about that after Simeon talked to her, the Virgin Mary took the wound of sorrow and accepted God’s will.  What is that supposed to mean if I am trying to achieve a goal?

Thank you.

Comment: I, unfortunately, don't completely understand the question due to bad English. However, I think you are referring to the 4th joyful mystery if you want to read more on it see Luke 2,22-35. She was sad, sorrowful because she lost her Son, she didn't know He was in the Temple. Mary is also sorrowful at the time of Christ's death on the cross.

Comment: You're asking two questions: one about St. Mary's sorrows, and another about accepting God's will over one's own personal will. My answer below addresses only your first question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is the meaning of: “A Sword Will Pierce Your Soul”?**

In the fourth mystery of the Joyful Mysteries **[Quartum Mysterium Gaudiosum: Presentatio (the Presentation in the Temple)]** of the Most Holy Rosary of the Blessed Virgin Mary **(Mysteria Gaudiosa)**, we read the following:

> And thy own soul a sword shall pierce, that, out of many hearts, thoughts may be revealed. - [Luke 2: 35](https://biblehub.com/luke/2-35.htm)

Fr. George Rutler puts it this way:

> As Our Lady was virtually abandoned at the foot of the Cross, so have those who are suffering atrocities and genocide been scandalously ignored by many in the West until recently. Our government has announced that it will stop the State Department’s policy of directing all relief funds through ineffective agencies of the United Nations, and will work with private organizations to aid vulnerable religious and ethnic minorities.
>
> St. John Paul II said that Simeon’s prediction confirms Mary’s “faith in the accomplishment of the divine promises of salvation, [while] on the other hand it also reveals to her that she will have to live her obedience of faith in suffering, at the side of the suffering Savior, and that her motherhood will be mysterious and sorrowful.”
>
> As the pen is mightier than the sword, in Bulwer-Lytton’s adage, so is Christ the Living Word more acute and powerful than any sword that pierces those who love him. - [“A Sword Will Pierce Your Soul”](http://www.ncregister.com/blog/fatherrutler/a-sword-will-pierce-your-soul)

Thus we see that the very sins which offends Our Lord inflicts sorrow in the Immaculate Heart of Mary and in the hearts of those who truly united in love to Our Lord with all their heart and being. This is what we must achieve in this life and be willing to make reparation for the outrages committed against the Most Sacred Heart of Jesus.

[image: The Presentation of Our Lord in the Temple]

***The Presentation or Our Lord in the Temple***

Comment: I may interpret that Mary’s wound of sorrow is something possible and a strongly encouragement for my soul.

Answer (score 1):

The fourth Joyful Mystery of the [Holy Rosary](http://www.preces-latinae.org/thesaurus/BVM/Rosarium.html) is the Presentation of Jesus in the Temple, where the holy man Simeon prophesied that ([Luke 2:35](http://drbo.org/chapter/49002.htm)) her

> own soul a sword shall pierce, that, out of many hearts, thoughts may be revealed.

The Prophesy of Simeon is the first of the seven sorrows meditated upon in [the devotion to the Sorrowful Mother](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=5855).

In fact, [Mary's name in Hebrew, מַרְיָם (Mariam), means "bitter sea"](https://isidore.co/forum/index.php?topic=39).

From [*Devotion to the Sorrowful Mother*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=5855):

> The martyrdom of Mary was lifelong, for according to Simeon’s prophecy, she was enlightened with regard to the intense sufferings of her Divine Son. Her entire being was steeped in bitterness. The swords which pierced her soul penetrated also every nerve and fiber of her tender, sinless body. To her was wanting that great support which the martyrs enjoyed in their sufferings. During their torments, they directed their inward gaze toward Jesus, the Crucified, by whose grace and love they were strengthened and consoled. The flames of the love of Jesus cooled the fires of torture, softened the strokes of the scourges, and blunted the sharpness of the sword.

Comment: The website etymonline.com, which gets much of its etymological material from the OED, states that the name is " a word of unknown origin, said to mean literally 'rebellion.'" I've seen this interpretation in a number of places, so I'd be cautious about definitively stating the interpretation of her name. Source: https://www.etymonline.com/word/Mary?ref=etymonline_crossreference

Comment: @MattGutting Protestant sources seem to think that. St. Jerome writes ([_Liber de Nominibus Hebraicis_ col. 886](https://archive.org/details/sanctieusebiihie02jero/page/n444): "Mariam plerique aestimant interpretari, illuminant me isti, vel illuminatrix, vel Smyrna maris, sed mihi nequaquam videtur. Melius autem est, ut dicamus sonare eam stellam maris, sive amarum mare:  sciendumque quod Maria, sermone Syro domina nuncupetur."

Comment: @MattGutting ["Many, they tell me, think _Maria_ means either illuminator or the Smyrna sea, but it does not at all seem so to me. For it is better that we say it signifies the star of the sea or bitter sea: and understanding that _Maria_ in Syrian means lady."]

Comment: @MattGutting The _OED_ for "[Mary](https://oed.com/view/Entry/114528)" says nothing about "rebellion"; it says: «The Hebrew name may be < Amorite, with the meaning ‘gift (of God)’; compare the Akkadian root rym ‘to give as a gift’. […] one element of the name has often been interpreted as ‘sea’, e.g. in pseudo-Epiphanius' explanation σμύρνα θαλάσσης ‘myrrh of the sea’ […] and St Jerome's _stella maris_»

Comment: I have never heard of your interpretation as to the meaning of the Holy Name of Mary. The [Catholic Encyclopedia](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/15464a.htm) favours **exalted one**, the **beautiful one** or the **perfect one**. It goes into great detail on the meaning of Our Lady’s name.

Comment: @KenGraham Which interpretation? (Thanks for the link to the _CE_ article! I didn't know it had such an article.)

Comment: I do not think “**Mary**” means “**bitter sea**”. It is most likely originally an Egyptian name, perhaps derived in part from mry "beloved" or mr "love". It is an absolute shame that we actually stick to English sources, whereas the French name Marie means something a little more interesting: Saint Jérôme rapporte, que de son temps la plupart interprètent ce mot par "illuminatrix", et ils le dérivent par conséquent de l'hébreu "meirab", qui est le participatif féminin du verbe "heir", éclairer. [Source](https://sites.google.com/site/etymologielatingrec/home/m/marie).

Comment: @KenGraham [St. Jerome thought it could mean "bitter sea"](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/41965/8491), too. (Your French source appears to be a paraphrase of St. Jerome's etymology of Maria in _Liber de Nominibus Hebraicis_, quoted [here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/41965/8491).)